# MySQL SELECT unique column where other column is max

Tags: mysql, select, unique, max

I have table like this

```
  id     |     serial_num     |      version     | .....
  1      |         1          |          1       | .....
  2      |         2          |          1       | .....
  3      |         2          |          2       | .....
  4      |         3          |          1       | .....
  5      |         4          |          1       | .....
  6      |         5          |          1       | .....
  7      |         5          |          2       | .....
  8      |         5          |          3       | .....
```

Now what I want to select is to get rows with max version and unique serialn_num ...

The result would be:

```
  id     |     serial_num     |      version     | .....
  1      |         1          |          1       | .....
  3      |         2          |          2       | .....
  4      |         3          |          1       | .....
  5      |         4          |          1       | .....
  8      |         5          |          3       | .....
```

My SQL is a bit more complicated and that is why I don't solve the problem by using MAX()... I have few left joins etc ...

any ideas?

Best regards and thank you for your time!

Comment: Can you explain the result a little more, what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Sure ... sorry not to explain before ... 

It should work as kind of revisioning system with attached date ( marked as ...) ..

At this point I want to SELECT all new data (MAX version) and I want it to be unique (serial_num) ...

I don't want to solve this using MAX() because I could get wrong data... Let say SELECT id, MAX(version), MAX(serial_num) from t GROUP BY serial_num could return wrong ID since it is not in MAX() ... I hope I explained well..

Comment: how do you determine which `id` you pick for a unique `serial_num`?  e.g. seems like it is max(id) for each unique serial_num

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT yourtable.*
FROM yourtable
WHERE (serial_num, version) in (select serial_num, max(version)
                                from yourtable
                                group by serial_num)
```

Subquery will return the maximum version for serial_num, so this will return all rows where serial_num has the maximum value. See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26943/1/0).

Comment: why not just using this? `select id, serial_num, max(version) AS Version                                from yourtable group by serial_num`

Comment: Great! This ine works... Now one more think I thought about ... I have date column also ... and on new year counter for serial_num reset ... I should somehow check this as well...

Comment: @M.V. thanks for confirming. that was my initial query. I had to add `max(id)` for you.

Comment: What if I also have date value? any idea? It can be (DATE, SERIAL, VERSION) (2012, 1, 1), (2012, 2, 1), (2013, 1, 1)

Comment: SELECT yourtable.*
FROM yourtable
WHERE (yeartime, serial_num, version) in (select yeartime, serial_num, max(version)
                                from yourtable
                                group by yeartime, serial_num)

Comment: This helps solving additional problem!

Comment: @M.V. if you are sure that ID is always increasing, you can just use this: `select yourtable2.* from yourtable2 where id in (select max(id) from yourtable2 group by serial_num)`

Comment: @P1nGu1n you are selecting `id` and `serial_num` (and max), but you are grouping by only `serial_num`, this will return undetermined results for `id` and all nonaggregated columns that are not in group by (`id` will probably have the first encountered value, but we can't rely on it, it could be any other id in aggregated group)

Comment: When an ID is used multiple times, it's not an identifier anymore and should therefore never be used more then once. For that reason I haven not taken it into account.

Comment: @M.V. if id is not enough, pls see fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7d8e/1/1

Comment: @P1nGu1n of course, but i think that OP is interested in getting also other columns that are not specified in question, you could use a group by on a subquery ordered by date desc, version, this will probably get the correct answer (it usually will) but according to the documentation it shouldn't work http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subquery to find the max values and then join back to your table:

```
select t1.id,
  t1.serial_num,
  t1.version
from yourtable t1
inner join
(
  select serial_num, 
    max(version) version
  from yourtable
  group by serial_num
) t2
  on t1.serial_num = t2.serial_num
  and t1.version = t2.version
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df214/7)

Result:

```
| ID | SERIAL_NUM | VERSION |
-----------------------------
|  1 |          1 |       1 |
|  3 |          2 |       2 |
|  4 |          3 |       1 |
|  5 |          4 |       1 |
|  8 |          5 |       3 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Selecting `id` for a group by query is useless. You should only select the column you are using in group by and other columns that are being applied aggregate functions.

Hope [this works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14159792/mysql-select-unique-column-where-other-column-is-max/14159914#comment19615098_14159834) for you.

```
SELECT id, 
       serial_num, 
       Max(`version`) `version`
FROM   tbl1 
GROUP  BY serial_num
```