# Group by ID, select only the newest record for each

Tags: sql, sqlite

Each row in my table is the status of a station at a given time. It has a lot of things that change over time. Water flow, tempature, ect. I want to be able to return the most recent record from each station. Not all of the stations update at the same time so I am not able to just grab the last few records and know that I have them all.

```
Flow    Sortdate    Station
-----------------------------------------
164     2013-07-19  11502940
520     2013-07-19  11502500
164     2013-07-20  11502940
520     2013-07-20  11502500
164     2013-07-21  11502940
520     2013-07-21  11502500
```

I would think that this should work.

```
select station, sortdate, flow from dailymean 

group by  Station
order by sortdate DESC
```

It does not. I have looked on here and someone had something like this.

```
select f.station, f.date, f.flow from dailymean f,dailymean second on second.station=f.station 
where f.station>second.station,
group by  f.Station
order by f.sortdate DESC
```

That will kick out the oldest set of records, but will return all of the others, not just the newest ones.

Just to be clear I need more than just the date it was last updated. I also need the water flow and many other things from the last time that each station was updated. I am using SQLite.

Comment: You should consider reviewing your data structure. What you want to achieve is easier and cleaner with two separate tables.

Comment: Try to add `LIMIT n` clause at the end of your query to fetch n latest rows, SQLite implemets this feature: [link](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
SELECT
  dailymean.Station,
  dailymean.Flow,
  dailymean.Sortdate
FROM
  dailymean
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Station, MAX(Sortdate) AS maxDate FROM dailymean GROUP BY Station
  ) AS Tmp ON dailymean.Station = Tmp.Station
          AND dailymean.Sortdate = Tmp.maxDate
```

[(Live code here)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/27748/1/0)

Answer (score 2):

Basically what you want is all the columns from the table where the sortdate is maximal for that station. Doing this in sql is a bit messy, as you can see here: [MySQL SELECT unique column where other column is max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14159792/mysql-select-unique-column-where-other-column-is-max)

The query for your schema would be, if I'm not making any mistakes

```
SELECT *
FROM dailymean
WHERE (station, sortdate) IN
    (SELECT station, MAX(sortdate)
     FROM dailymean
     GROUP BY station)
```

Comment: That looks good, but when I try it and different variations on it, I still get errors. Maybe a SQLite thing?

Comment: Every version of SQL is slightly different. I think MySQL would require the subquery to be given an alias. What errors are you seeing?

Comment: Alternative syntax:
`SELECT *
FROM dailymean, (SELECT station, MAX(sortdate)
     FROM dailymean
     GROUP BY station) AS i
WHERE dailymean.station = i.station AND dailymean.sortdate = i.sortdate`