# mysql - Select unique column based on max value of another column in a different table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I'm trying to select only the highest *kw* (`model` table) for each *category* (`type` table).

**Model table**

```
+-----+----+---------+
| id  | kw | type_id |
+-----+----+---------+
|   1 |  2 |       1 |
|   2 |  5 |       1 |
|   3 | 10 |       2 |
|   4 |  4 |       2 |
|   5 |  5 |       2 |
|   6 |  4 |       3 |
|   7 |  3 |       4 |
|   8 |  7 |       5 |
+-----+----+---------+
```

**Type table**

```
+-----+----------+
| id  | category |
+-----+----------+
|   1 |        1 | 
|   2 |        1 |
|   3 |        2 |
|   4 |        2 |
|   5 |        2 |
+-----+----------+
```

**Attempts** 
1. this query returns a list of all the *kws* and *categories*:

```
SELECT A.kw, B.category
FROM AC_MODEL A
INNER JOIN AC_TYPE B ON A.type_id = B.id
ORDER BY A.kw DESC
```

2. I tried to do something like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14159792/mysql-select-unique-column-where-other-column-is-max) but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT A.kw, B.category
FROM AC_MODEL A
INNER JOIN AC_TYPE B ON A.type_id = B.id
ORDER BY A.kw DESC 
WHERE (A.kw, B.category) IN (
    SELECT MAX(A.kw), B.category 
    FROM AC_MODEL A
    INNER JOIN AC_TYPE B ON A.type_id = B.id
    GROUP BY B.category
)
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `MAX` and `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT MAX(m.kw), t.category
FROM model m
INNER JOIN type t ON m.type_id = t.id
GROUP BY t.category
```

OUTPUT

```
MAX(m.kw)   category
10          1
7           2
```

SQL FIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d0df/5/0